# How to render user interface when there is no inputs for a certain fields

Tags: usability, design

We capture various messages in a certain form and the user might fill out only say 10 out of the 30 messages which were presented to him.

e.g. messages given below.

```
Login Message: 
Welcome Message:
Action Success Message:
Action Failure Message:
```

If we show all the 30 labels with only 10 of them filled, the screen doesn't look nice. How should we handle this?

Assuming these messages are broken in 3 sections, with 10 messages each and the user fills say 2 each in all 3 sections. How should we handle this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to demonstrate? Do you have any feedback from users that suggest there are any particular problems with the design?

Answer (score 1):

I would hesitate to design the interface based on the desired look and feel. You should probably look at a better grouping of the form that will help break the messages into smaller sections that can then be better tailored to the content as well as how users will interact with the information.

In terms of the actual visual design, as long as you make it clear that the difference between  an editable versus static field is clear, and also the labels are distinguishable from the values then I don't think it will look too bad.